# TypeORM's migration:generate regenerates the whole database schema

Tags: typeorm

Every time I run `migration:generate`, it creates a migration that regenerates the entire database schema (rather than a migration for just the recent changes to my entities). I'm using Typeorm version 0.2.7, the latest version.

My `ormconfig.json` is:

```json
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "logging": false,
  "port": 5432,
  "synchronize": false,
  "type": "postgres",

  "entities": ["build/server/entity/*.js"],
  "migrations": ["build/server/migration/*.js"],

  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "build/server/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "build/server/migration"
  },

  "username": "***",
  "password": "***",
  "database": "***"
}
```

When I run `typeorm migration:generate -n SomeEntityChanges`, the new migration file contains instructions for creating and linking up tables for *all* my entities, even though most of them already have corresponding migrations in `build/server/migration`.

When I run `typeorm migration:run`, I can see that there are no pending migrations, and that the migrations that cover the existing entities have been run (i.e. they're in my `migrations` table).

What am I missing? The [docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/migrations.md#generating-migrations) say that the `migration:generate` command should just generate a migration with the recent changes.

Comment: I also have the same problem with postgres :-?

Comment: @hungneox try removing `{schema: 'public'}` if you have it in your Entities

Answer (score 10):

This might sound really stupid but I was having the same issue and the problem was the name of my database. My database name was `mydbLocal` with a capital L, but when typeorm was reading in order to generate a new migration it would look for `mydblocal` and since there was no schema with that name it caused the generation to regenerate the whole schema. It seems like it is a bug because on the parsing of the schema it looked for the lower case one but when running the migration it went into the real one (upper case L).

Anyway the way I solved it was by changing my db name to all lowercase and also editing my ormconfig database name to be all lowercase.

It is a really strange situation but this solved my problem. Hopefully it will help someone else too.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned is one of the previous answers, the issue for me was indeed camel-casing the database name. Changing database name to all lowercase seems to have fixed the migration generate issue.

However, in my new project, I noticed that the entity table name override also seems to have the same behavior. Strangely, this was not an issue in the previous projects for me.

```js
//Previous table name causing migration file to regenerate    
@Entity({
  name: 'TempTable',
})

//New table name which stops the regeneration   
@Entity({
  name: 'temp_table',
})
```

Hope this helps someone facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm having exactly this issue on MySQL with PascalCase table names. If I lowercase the table name in the entity decorator `@Entity('tablename'` the table is recognised as existing and the `CREATE TABLE` doesn't get generated, changing the table names to lowercase isn't an option for me in this project though. Such a pain.

Answer (score 3):

Removing `{schema: 'public'}` from the all of my `@Entity` definitions fixed it for me with Postgresql

Previous:
`@Entity({schema: 'public'})`

Working:
`@Entity()`

Comment: Having the same problem on MySQL with nothing like `{ schema: "public" }` in my code.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted for a solution that worked for me

Comment: As a follow up here, this annotation showed up for me as I had an existing database that I was working against and I used an automatic code generator to create the entities.  I am not sure why it did, but removing `{schema: 'public'}` did the trick.  Sadly, changing the case of my tables (as mentioned in answers in other questions) is out of scope for me

Answer (score 0):

It is because your database is probably empty. TypeOrm computes the diff between your actual codebase entities and your actual database, thus generating the migration.

Check your ormconfig.json, as it is what is read by typeorm CLI to generate the migration, it probably points to an empty database, thus generating all tables in the migration.

Just migrate on your database, and run generate again.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem on a clean database which generates the correct migration the first time, populates the database with the entities, then generates the same migration the second time. Database is definitely not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I kept having this issue on MySQL and after hours of tinkering I finally resolved the problem.

Assuming the `{ schema: "public" }` fix didn't work for you, here are the actions I had to take to clean up a terrible migration generation.

First of all, make sure you're running the latest version of TypeORM. I was down by a few minor version, and this alone was enough to give me **countless** index-based errors.

If you're up to date, great! Here's the bad news: your entities are wrong. The biggest issue I kept running into was the `default` property on **most** of my duplications. From what I've come to understand, both Postgres and MySQL return different-than-expected results when TypeORM is trying to compare database defaults to the defined default.

For example: on a type "decimal" with a 4-digit trailing decimal, `default: 0` works fine when building your column, but MySQL actually returns `"0.0000"`, meaning no matter how many times you run this update, the default will never be a literal zero. TypeORM sees this being different, and wants to change the existing MySQL default back to a normal zero.

This error spanned across everything from `default: null` to "tinyint" booleans being listed as int in my schema.

Read the generated output carefully and check each entity for the property being mentioned. Some of this was fixed by updating to the latest version of TypeORM, but I managed to completely clear almost 250 table alterations by ensuring the default data actually matched what MySQL stores.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, my solution was not pretty decent but actually "works".

In the migration with the whole database, search for the tables involved, filter them, and delete all the other queries generated by typeorm, after deleted, run the migration command and it will work, creating/altering the tables you desired.

It's not scalable but remember, [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/using-cli.md#create-a-new-migration) they specify to alter only few tables before migration. 
`The rule of thumb is to generate a migration after each entity change.`

Answer (score 0):

1st
pay attention to lowercase or upercase

2nd
if u use upsercase name put it on ""

3rd
if u use schema add it to ormconfig
like:

```
"schema": "public",
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

In my case after around four migrations new migrations consisted of old changes. Searched the web, checked/tried the other answers from here. The only thing which helped in my case was just to remove the project, clone it again, setting it up again (adding the .env, run npm install), run the current migrations, generating the new migration file with only the new changes as expected. Of course this is not showing the root cause, but after that I could continue working without problems.

```
rm -rf project
git clone project
cd project
npm ci
ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli migration:run
```

These two comments ([1](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1686#issuecomment-851391331), [2](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1686#issuecomment-889655821)) made me try this.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old but dwsndev's answer solved it for me. (I can't comment with <50 reputation.) I had this issue with nullable varchar fields being altered to the same definition on each migration. Setting a default via a function fixed it:

```
 @Column({
    type: "varchar",
    nullable: true,
    default: () => `NULL`,
  })
  public text?: string;
```

For more, see this issue: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7287

Answer (score -3):

You should use `migration:create` instead of `migration:generate`. What I recommend is, inside your `package.json`:

```js
{
  ...
  scripts: {
    "migration:create": "NODE_ENV=local npm run typeorm -- migration:create -n",
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm"
  }
}
```

then you can just run:

```sh
$ npm run migration:create NameOfYourMigration
```

to create your migration successfully.

Comment: but compared to :generate the migration file is empty. How to add the changes automatically without the adding all the other stuff to it.

Comment: this is not the question